# Convert set to regex pattern in clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

If I have this set

```
(def my-set #{"foo.clj" "bar.clj" "baz.clj"})
```

How can I turn it to this pattern string:

```
"foo\.clj|bar\.clj|baz\.clj"
```

My attempt :

```
(defn set->pattern-str [coll] 
  (-> (clojure.string/join "|" coll) 
      (clojure.string/replace #"\." "\\\\.")))

(set->pattern-str my-set) 
=> "foo\\.clj|baz\\.clj|bar\\.clj" ;I get the double backslash
```

Better ideas?

Comment: can parenthesis be nested?

Comment: can you give ideone.com link of the running code?

Comment: http://ideone.com/aO7X8h but it doesn't seem to work. I get no output... Maybe `clojure.string` not supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case your set of strings might have other metacharacters than just `.` in them, a more general approach is to [ask the underlying `java.util.regex.Pattern` implementation to escape everything for us](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
(import 'java.util.regex.Pattern)

(defn set->pattern-str [coll] 
  (->> coll
    (map #(Pattern/quote %))
    (clojure.string/join \|)
     re-pattern))
```

[IDEone link here](http://ideone.com/wYBgIz). Remember, IDEone is not a REPL, and you have to tell it to put values on stdout with e.g. `println` before you can see them.

Comment: Instead of `(apply str)` I think you need to join individual quoted patterns with `|`, e.g. `(clojure.string/join "|")`. Otherwise it won't match correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that for a second. Probably a better solution there.

Comment: @Magos Yes! A more general approach seems good idea. Files have also often `-` in their names...

Answer (score 2):

You were close to the final solution. Double backslash is displayed because it is shown escaped. When you turn it into a `seq` you will see individual characters:

```
(seq "foo\\.clj")
;;=> (\f \o \o \\ \. \c \l \j)
```

And working solution:

```
(def my-set #{"foo.clj" "bar.clj" "baz.clj"})

(def my-set-pattern
  (-> (clojure.string/join "|" my-set)
    (clojure.string/replace "." "\\.")
    (re-pattern)))

(re-matches my-set-pattern "foo.clj")
;;=> "foo.clj"

(re-matches my-set-pattern "bar.clj")
;;=> "bar.clj"

(re-matches my-set-pattern "baz.clj")
;;=> "baz.clj"

(re-matches my-set-pattern "foo-clj")
;;=> nil
```

Comment: Right! Thanks for the `seq` explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: OK, this one does in fact work. Probably want to break it apart a bit more if it's meant to be long lived code, but this is the simplest way I could find to do it with minimal string munging.

```
(defn is-matching-file-name [target-string]
  (re-matches 
    (re-pattern (clojure.string/escape (String/join "|" my-set) {\. "\\."}))
    target-string))
```

The clojure.string/escape here takes two arguments: the string to escape, and a mapping of the characters to escape to the replacement strings. The key in this map is the literal `\.` and the value needs two backslashes since we want to include one backslash preceding any `.` in the final string to be used as the argument for the re-pattern function.